# How to Specify a diagonal matrix using tf.get_variable

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, diagonal

I am trying to create a diagonal matrix using tf.get_variable
But I do not know how!
Like I can make a variable which is a diagonal matrix like:

```
dia_size = tf.zeros((num_filters, img_size))
b = tf.Variable(tf.matrix_diag(dia_size), name=name)
b = tf.reshape(b, [-1, img_size, img_size, num_filters])
```

but I can not do it with tf.get_variable.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `initializer` parameter of `tf.get_variable` to a tensor, the variable will be initialized to the tensor's value. Therefore, you can use the following code:

```
dia_size = tf.zeros((num_filters, img_size))
b = tf.matrix_diag(dia_size)
var = tf.get_variable(..., initializer=b, ...)
```