# set diagonal values of tensor to 0

Tags: tensorflow

It seems that there is no simple way to assign a value to the diagonal of a Tensor.  Ideally I am looking for a command like numpy.fill_diagonal.

Currently I accomplish this by doing:

```
tf.matrix_set_diag(
                matrix,
                tf.zeros_like(matrix.shape[0:-1]),
                name=None
            )
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe this link can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47425424/how-to-specify-a-diagonal-matrix-using-tf-get-variable

Answer (score 2):

I think your answer should be:

```
tf.matrix_set_diag(matrix, tf.zeros(matrix.shape[0:-1]), name=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be updated to `tf.linalg.set_diag`, which can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/set_diag.)